# Why basic arithmetic operators don't need math.h library

Tags: c

I got a question from my fellow student friend about why +-/* don't need math.h library to work in C language.

Comment: Understand the difference between language and library...

Comment: Why should they require a library?  Libraries provide *function* implementations, and in C, operators are not functions.

Comment: Why should they need math.h?

Comment: Declaring a variable doesn't need `#include <variables.h>` either, after all. :)

Answer (score 4):

`<math.h>` contains macro and function definitions for mathematical operations. Some of the functionality in `<math.h>` is required to be present according to the C Standard, but they still aren't intrinsically part of the grammar of the language, unlike the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [C Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm), notice they are all fairly simple operations that can be done on numbers and values without the need of a function call (sqrt()). These are part of the C standard and are a basic part of the language, present by default in every program.

The [math.h Library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm) contains far more complex mathematical operations, mostly in functions, not small assembly instructions. These do not need to be included in the language because not every program is going to need a square root or a cosine.

Comment: `math.h` is part of C standard

Answer (score 1):

Because they are in the standard of C and they are only one instruction in Assembly language. `math.h` is only the name of the library. That doesn't mean there are no math if you don't include it.

Comment: "only one instruction in Assembly language" -> not necessarily. SPARC 7, for example, doesn't have a multiplication or division instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Basic operators are part of the grammar of the language. In a lib there are "higher functions" that are composed out of basic operators or other libs. So you can reduce everythink back to the basic constructs of a language ... certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operators are built into the language grammar - they're not separate library calls like `sqrt()` or `abs()` or whatever.  So, they don't need to have any sort of declaration in scope in order to function.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, the reason `math.h` is needed for some operations and not others is that the people who designed C decided to build some things into the core language and to keep some things in separate sets, including a set of things for math, a set of things for strings, a set of things for time, a set of things for input and output, and so on.

It would be possible to build the things in `math.h` into the core language. For example, `sizeof` is built into the language, so building `sqrt` into the language too would not require any change of grammar. Also, it would be theoretically possible to exclude some operations like `*` from the core language and require you to include `math.h` before using them. However, the language provides ways for declaring functions like `sqrt` but does not provide ways for declaring operators like `*`, so some changes to the grammar would have to be made to support this.

So, since it is **possible** the core language could include or exclude various things, then the reasons for various things being included or excluded are somewhat a matter of choice. Essentially, the basic arithmetic operations were considered fundamental and very useful, so they were made part of the core language, while other functions were not. There are various factors contributing to this.

One is a desire to avoid cluttering the language. If all of the functions declared in headers were part of the core language, then `sqrt` could be used only for the `sqrt` in `math.h`. A programmer could not use `sqrt` for their own variable name. This is fine for a few names, but, as the library grows, the chance there will be collisions between a name in a library and a name in regular source code grows.

Additionally, if there is existing source code and somebody has a bright idea for a new routine, adding the new routine name to the language might break existing code that is already using that name for a different purpose.

So, generally, we prefer to implement non-essential routines in separate sets, and then authors can choose to include the ones they want to use and learn, and they can leave out the ones they do not need and avoid problems.

Partitioning the libraries into sets like this also means that library routines not used by a program do not have to be linked into the final program executable, so the executable file can be smaller.

Additionally, it means C can be used in a variety of environments, such as a small machine that is not able to support the full math library. Somebody might want to run simple programs that just work with basic arithmetic on a small processor. If the core language of C is small, they can write such programs. If every C program had to include all of the routines on the libraries, it might not be possible to get C working on very small computers.